# Talking to an Arduino: works in C#, fails in Python

Tags: c#, python, arduino

I need to talk to an Arduino Pro Micro controller hooked up to an USB port. The sketch uploaded to it should respond to a standard C# string with debug response:

```
> #NAME
>>> ARDUINO
```

(The request string doesn't have line feed terminator.) Serial port monitor in Arduino IDE gets proper response from connected Arduino.

I wrote a C# program to test communication myself and it also gets the proper response:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static SerialPort port;

    // static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    //    // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
    //    Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
    //}

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        port = new SerialPort("COM5", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        //            port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;

        Console.WriteLine("Port: " + port.PortName);

        port.Open();

        if (!port.IsOpen) {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't open port.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Writing '#NAME' to port...");
        port.Write("#NAME");

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        string ans = port.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + ans + "| " + ans.Length);

        port.Close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Port: COM5
Writing '#NAME' to port...
Response: ARDUINO | 9
```

I tried to talk to the controller using Python and pySerial module:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

# msg = b'\x00\x23\x00\x4e\x00\x41\x00\x4d\x00\x45\n'
# msg = b'\x23\x4e\x41\x4d\x45\n'
# msg = b'#NAME\n'
# msg = b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00N\x00\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00M\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x00'
# msg = b'\xff\xfe#\x00N\x00A\x00M\x00E\x00'
# msg = bytes('#NAME', encoding="utf-8")
# msg = bytes('#NAME', encoding="utf-16")
# msg = bytearray([0x23, 0x4E, 0x41, 0x4D, 0x45])
# msg = bytearray(b"#NAME")
msg = "#NAME".encode("utf-16")

port = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, bytesize=8, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=2)

print("Port:", port.name)
print("Is open?:", port.is_open)
print("Writing:", msg)

# port.writelines([msg])
port.write(msg)

sleep(1)

output = port.read_until(size=len(msg))
# output = port.read_all()
print("Reading:", output)

port.close()
```

But I couldn't get it to respond correctly:

```
Port: COM5
Is open? True
Writing: b'\xff\xfe#\x00N\x00A\x00M\x00E\x00'
Reading: b''
```

pySerial's write methods don't work with strings and only accept byte sequences, so I tried converting strings with different methods.

Since the port and the controller both work correctly, I thought that it might be a problem with my Python or pySerial installation, so I tried testing them. I have an another controller, which simply echoes any input byte sequences it gets. Test run with the same Python program:

```
Port: COM5
Is open? True
Writing: b'\xff\xfe#\x00N\x00A\x00M\x00E\x00'
Reading: b'\xff\xfe#\x00N\x00A\x00M\x00E\x00'
```

Can someone, please, explain, what's happening and how can I talk to the first controller using Python?

UPDATE:

I used a serial port monitor program to watch data streams:

Arduino IDE serial monitor data exchange log ('#NAME', no endline bytes, baudrate=115200):

```
Port opened by process "javaw.exe" (PID: 2792)

Request: 27.12.2017 16:24:37.38864
 23 4E 41 4D 45                                    #NAME           

Answer: 27.12.2017 16:24:37.58964 (+0.2010 seconds)
 41 52 44 55 49 4E 4F 0D 0A                        ARDUINO..       

Port closed
```

C# program exchange log ('#NAME', no endline bytes, baudrate=115200):

```
Port opened by process "ConsoleApplication1.exe" (PID: 7004)

Request: 27.12.2017 16:31:24.69564 (+26.5445 seconds)
 23 4E 41 4D 45                                    #NAME           

Answer: 27.12.2017 16:31:26.72564 (+2.0291 seconds)
 41 52 44 55 49 4E 4F 0D 0A                        ARDUINO..       

Port closed
```

Python program exchange log (b'#NAME', no endline bytes, baudrate=115200):

```
Port opened by process "python.exe" (PID: 2416)

Request: 27.12.2017 16:39:32.00464 (+139.8020 seconds)
 23 4E 41 4D 45                                    #NAME           

Port closed
```

All three programs write the same byte sequence, I don't understand, why the Python program doesn't get the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, my controller device was at fault. I still don't know why it didn't respond to a request sent with Python while it did respond using both C# and Arduino IDE, but after replacing it with a new device, I got the desired response in all environments.

Answer (score 2):

You are using UTF16-Encoding with BOM, which most likely isn't correct. Normally these protocols expect ASCII with newline characters:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

msg = "#NAME\r\n".encode('ascii')
port = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, bytesize=8, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=2)

print("Port:", port.name)
print("Is open?:", port.is_open)
print("Writing:", msg)

port.write(msg)
sleep(1)

output = port.read_until(size=len(msg))
print("Reading:", output)

port.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I was worried that I'm mismatching input byte sequence format. Unfortunately, it is a legacy sketch and it was written without regards to standard practices. The test sequence does not use any endline bytes. Turns out, the problem might run deeper than just encoding mismatch. I have updated my post, please, take a look if you find some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try `msg = msg.decode('ascii')` or `msg = msg.decode('utf-16')` before you print the outcome. That is before the line `print("Writing:", msg)`.
I ran into a similar problem and tried this and it worked for me.